# Is it possible for a tkinter root window to be switched during processing?

Tags: python, tkinter

For my NEA, I am trying to code my own program, with this program I want to be able to have as few windows open as possible so i want to be able to switch the first root window into an alternate window. When this occurs i want it so that the root window shuts and is replaced but i am unable to figure out how to do that. Is it possible to be able to close the root window and switch it mid processing or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this behave the way you want?
Press F1 key to switch between Tk windows.
Press Escape or Click on Close button to close both.

```py
import tkinter

def windowlink( o, f, title = 'Window' ):
    o.title( string = title )
    o.protocol( 'WM_DELETE_WINDOW', f )
    b = o.bind( '<KeyRelease-Escape>', f )

master_A = tkinter.Tk( )
master_A.withdraw()
master_A.geometry( '281x200+380+153' )

master_B = tkinter.Tk( )
master_B.withdraw()
master_B.geometry( '281x200+380+153' )


def closer( ev = None ):
    master_A.destroy()
    master_B.destroy()

def switchAB( ev = None ):
    master_A.withdraw()
    master_B.deiconify()
    master_B.focus_set()

def switchBA( ev = None ):
    master_B.withdraw()
    master_A.deiconify()
    master_A.focus_set()

windowlink( master_B, closer, title= 'Window_B' )
tkinter.Button( master_B, text = 'Switch window', command = switchBA ).grid( row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew' )

windowlink( master_A, closer, title= 'Window_A' )
tkinter.Button( master_A, text = 'Switch window', command = switchAB ).grid( row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew' )


master_B.deiconify()
master_B.focus_set()

tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't use F1, it is a shortcut key to open the python docs in IDEs

Comment: This does behave in the way i want but i want to implement the command so it works from a button within the window. Also what does .withdraw() , .deiconify() , .focus_set() and .protocol do?

Comment: @TeeGee `.withdraw` hides the window, `.deiconify` shows the window, `.focus_set` sets the focus on that window. When using: `protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", <function>)`, it binds to the `X` in the window titlebar and calls `<function>` when it's pressed.

Comment: @PCM you are correct, F1 is used to open docs but only in Idle editor and shell. Once the program is running All keys are available to tkinter user.

Comment: @TeeGee I've modified demo program with buttons. Happy Coding

Comment: @Derek: _"Once the program is running All keys are available to tkinter user"_ - not _all_ keys. The OS usually reserves a tiny handful for its own use. One obvious example is control-alt-delete on windows.

Comment: @BryanOakley yes I was a bit broad with my answer. Function keys F10 to F12 for example are not available.

Comment: I get them right now and then@TeeGee. Happy Coding.